# JavaFX: Blank rows in FXML TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-tableview

I've been trying to add a row of information from my Product class to this tableView:

[image: Empty Table]

When I hit the add button and run:

`productTableView.getItems().add(new Product(...)`

It adds a blank row to my table:

[image: Table After Add()]

#### Controller.java

```
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class Controller {

// Initialized all elements of GUI
public TableView<Product> productTableView;
public TableColumn<Product, Integer> productID;
public TableColumn<Product, String> name;
public TableColumn<Product, Double> price;
public TableColumn<Product, Integer> quantity;
public TableColumn<Product, Double> cost;
public TableColumn<Product, Date> bought;
public TableColumn<Product, Date> sold;
public TableColumn<Product, Integer> threshold;                 

public void addProduct() {                                           
      productTableView.getItems().add(new Product( 1, "Toilet Paper", 9.99, 1.25, 300, 300, new Date(), new Date())
    );
}
```

#### Inventory_Management.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>
<VBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Inventory_Management.Controller">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="productTableView" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <columns>
             <TableColumn fx:id="productID" prefWidth="75.0" text="Product ID">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="productID" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>

             <TableColumn fx:id="name" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name">
             <cellValueFactory>
                 <PropertyValueFactory property="name" />
             </cellValueFactory>
             </TableColumn>

            <TableColumn fx:id="price" prefWidth="75.0" text="Price">
             <cellValueFactory>
                 <PropertyValueFactory property="price" />
             </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>

            <TableColumn fx:id="quantity" prefWidth="75.0" text="Quantity">
             <cellValueFactory>
                 <PropertyValueFactory property="quantity" />
             </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn fx:id="cost" prefWidth="75.0" text="Cost">
             <cellValueFactory>
                 <PropertyValueFactory property="cost" />
             </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn fx:id="bought" prefWidth="75.0" text="Bought">
             <cellValueFactory>
                 <PropertyValueFactory property="bought" />
             </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn fx:id="sold" prefWidth="75.0" text="Sold">
             <cellValueFactory>
                 <PropertyValueFactory property="sold" />
             </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn fx:id="threshold" prefWidth="75.0" text="Threshold">
             <cellValueFactory>
                 <PropertyValueFactory property="threshold" />
             </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
         </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="30.0" left="30.0" right="30.0" top="30.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

I built the FXML using Scene Builder. I'm not sure how to implement the rows without creating the table programmatically. The data I input should be appearing in the table, but I'm not sure if its because of the way I'm implementing the row, or if there is something off with my PropertyValues.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that in my Product class, I did not have the appropriate getters and setters.

My getters in this case were case sensitive.

Example of "bad code":

```
public class Product {

    private int productID;

    public int getID() {
       return productID;
    }
}
```

Example of working code:

```
public int getProductID() {
    return productID;
}
```

A small difference, but important.